# How to check generated fake dns response message?

Tags: c, dns

I am trying to create a fake dns response message from a valid dns query.
I have finished the code and created the response message according to [RFC 1035](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) but I am not sure if it would work if I send it to the source. is there any way or tool to check the message my code generates is valid or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your program to receive DNS queries on UDP port 53 and to send your replies back. You can then use any DNS client to see if your answers are interpreted as desired. An example client is ISC `dig`, which can be run as `dig @127.0.0.1 example.com`. There are many examples on the web that illustrate how to build a simple DNS server; a particularly short one is https://github.com/wfelipe/simple-dns